# fetch between brackets on json with grep

Tags: linux, bash, command, json

i have the following json data

```
"url": "https://www.etsy.com/listing/812858182/59ft-x-84ft-moroccan-rug-mrirt-rug-beni?utm_source=etsymeter&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=api",
  "num_favorers": 26,
  "views": 69,
  "sku": [
    "Atlas115"
  ],
  "is_vintage": false
},
{
  "title": "Custom Beni ourain Authentic Moroccan rug, Berber carpet,rug, Handmade rug, Beni ourain style, Area rug, Tapis berbere, Berber rugs",
  "tags": [
    "beni ourain rug",
    "neutral rug",
    "moroccan rug",
    "boho rug",
    "kitchen rug",
    "area rugs",
    "shag rug",
    "Custom made rug",
    "Beniourain 5x7",
    "5x7 Beni ourain",
    "8x10 ft 4x6 ft",
    "5x8 4x6",
    "5x7 8x10 9x12"
  ],
  "url": "https://www.etsy.com/listing/887996258/custom-beni-ourain-authentic-moroccan?utm_source=etsymeter&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=api",
  "num_favorers": 63,
  "views": 436,
  "sku": [
    "GG002"
```

So i used grep to fetch all sku parameter and it show me this empty result :

```
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [
  "sku": [],
```

As you see in the first code  "sku": [
"Atlas115"
],
i would like to fetch all sku parameter with their attributes

Comment: The JSON code seems to be missing some bits. But if the top level is just a `[ ... ]` block, you could use `jq` for that, something like `jq -c '.[].sku'`

Comment: i did use jq but it's not yet the right command i did try jq '.results[].sku' it did give me just  sku values but if want to append another parameter such as tags it goes wrong in this way  jq '.results[].tags.sku' i dont know why

Comment: You can get more than one field of a JSON array with `jq` like this: `jq '.[] | .title, .sku'`

Comment: it did not work but i did try this one |  jq '.results[1].title , .results[1].tags  , .results[1].views'

Comment: You do not provide entire file, JSON you show is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying different cases of jq i came cross the right jq command for fetching the right data here is the command :

```
jq '.results[] | {sku}'
```

if you want to fetch more than field :

```
jq '.results[] | {title,sku}'
```